# HTML seems to think the page is scrolled down completely, i use Scrollreveal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use scrollreveal.js to make objects appear when scrolled to their position. When loading the page, it reveals all objects at once, as if I've passed them.

I added `reload: 'true'`, so it would reappear if I'd scroll up and the object would be in my view again, and that works.

Why doesn't it work when scrolling down?

Comment: You should add your code to understand the problem.

Comment: I figured it out, i was missing my doctype for some reason

Comment: Great. Glad to hear it.